# Why OnChange event is not getting fired upon changing a cell value in database table?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, console-application, sqldependency

I have been working on this code for the last 24 hours but it ain't working.

I want the **OnChange** event to get hit If I modify a cell in **Services** table but it doesn't, no matter what I do.

I have enabled the services broker on the database but still, it doesn't work.

Code:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var cs = Utility.getConnectionString();
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"Select [Services].[ServiceName], [Services].[ServicePrice] from dbo.Services", connection);
                SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnChange);
                SqlDependency.Start(cs);
                command.ExecuteReader().Dispose();
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Info);
        }
    }
```

Making changes to the db using edit more or update query.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnxpA.png)

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency(v=vs.110).aspx) : _SqlDependency allows you to receive notifications when the __original data in the database changes__ so that the cache can be refreshed._

Comment: @TaW: yes but it's not happening

Comment: Where in your code do you make any changes to the DB data??

Comment: I make change directly in the database using update query or edit mode

Comment: there is nothing that I didn't do to make it working but still it doesn't

Comment: eh wait, is not your code basically will drop the connection once it add the change hook and terminates? ._. it kind of weird if you actually make some change on the db after the code reaches that `ReadKey` part.. its pretty hard to make that change listener if it did not live long enough, and blocked by `ReadKey`.

Comment: so what to do ?

Comment: I have removed the read key. Still it doesn't

Comment: @BagusTesa: the readkey is not there anymore

Comment: You ought to have mentioned that your changes are done externally! - What do you mean you have removed the readkey? Your program teminates then simply doesn't it ?? - Also: The connection is terminated after the using block. Try to keep things alive, maybe (for testing) by inserting a `while (true) Application.DoEvents();` at the end of the using block.

Comment: @TaW: still not workin

Comment: there are whole lots of things you need to do to enable this, maybe you can refer to https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12862/Minimum-Database-Permissions-Required-for-SqlDepen

Comment: @Squirrel: the user is already DBOWNER

Answer (score 1):

Below is a worked example based on your code that displays `SqlNotificationEventArgs` values when the event is fired and re-subscribes only when valid.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        SqlDependency.Start(Utility.getConnectionString());

        GetDataWithSqlDependency();
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for data changes");
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to quit");
        Console.ReadKey();

        SqlDependency.Stop(Utility.getConnectionString());

    }

    static void GetDataWithSqlDependency()
    {

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Utility.getConnectionString()))
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [Services].[ServiceName], [Services].[ServicePrice] from dbo.Services;", connection))
        {
            var dependency = new SqlDependency(cmd);
            dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyChange);
            connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteReader().Dispose();
        }

    }
    static void OnDependencyChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {

        Console.WriteLine($"OnDependencyChange Event fired. SqlNotificationEventArgs: Info={e.Info}, Source={e.Source}, Type={e.Type}");

        if ((e.Info != SqlNotificationInfo.Invalid)
            && (e.Type != SqlNotificationType.Subscribe))
        {
            SqlDependency.Start(Utility.getConnectionString());
            GetDataWithSqlDependency();
            Console.WriteLine($"Data changed.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SqlDependency not restarted");
        }

    }

}

static class Utility
{
    public static string getConnectionString()
    {
        return @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=YourDatabase;Application Name=SqlDependencyExample;Integrated Security=SSPI";
    }

}
```

This is DDL for the test database:

```
CREATE DATABASE YourDatabase;
GO
ALTER DATABASE YourDatabase SET ENABLE_BROKER;
GO
USE YourDatabase;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Services(
      ServiceName varchar(100) NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT PK_Services PRIMARY KEY
    , ServicePrice decimal(10,2) NOT NULL
);
GO
```

These queries fire the OnChanged event:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Services VALUES('SomeService', 1.00);
GO
UPDATE dbo.Services SET ServicePrice = 2.00 WHERE ServiceName = 'SomeService';
GO
DELETE FROM dbo.Services WHERE ServiceName = 'SomeService';
GO
```

**EDIT:**

If you run your application using a minimally privileged account (a best practice), below is an example script to grant the minimum permissions needed for `SqlDependency`.

```
--create user for schema ownership
CREATE USER SqlDependencySchemaOwner WITHOUT LOGIN;
GO
--create schema for SqlDependency objects
CREATE SCHEMA SqlDependency AUTHORIZATION SqlDependencySchemaOwner;
GO

--add existing login as a minimally privileged database user with default schema SqlDependency
CREATE USER YourLogin WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = SqlDependency;

--grant user control permissions on SqlDependency schema
GRANT CONTROL ON SCHEMA::SqlDependency TO YourLogin;

--grant user impersonate permissions on SqlDependency schema owner
GRANT IMPERSONATE ON USER::SqlDependencySchemaOwner TO YourLogin;
GO

--grant database permissions needed to create and use SqlDependency objects
GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE TO YourLogin;
GRANT CREATE QUEUE TO YourLogin;
GRANT CREATE SERVICE TO YourLogin;
GRANT REFERENCES ON
    CONTRACT::[http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/PostQueryNotification] TO YourLogin;
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION TO YourLogin;
GRANT SELECT to YourLogin;
GRANT SUBSCRIBE QUERY NOTIFICATIONS TO YourLogin;
GRANT RECEIVE ON QueryNotificationErrorsQueue TO YourLogin;
GO

--grant permissions on user objects used by application
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.Services TO YourLogin;
GO
```

Comment: Are you saying this example code is not working for you? Is the `OnDependencyChange` method fired? If so, what values are displayed for the `OnDependencyChange` event arguments?

Comment: Done.

It was only because I haven't been using **sa** as a login. Only I changed my database to **sa** and used that in the connection string. It worked.

Comment: @jameel, I would have expected a `SqlException` if the non-sysadmin login didn't have the needed permissions. I updated my answer with the minimal permissions a non-sysadmin needs for SqlDependency.

Comment: thanks but I already had assigned it to the user who had all privileges but still it worked wth 'sa' only. Why ?

Comment: @jameel, do you mean you had granted the user the exact permissions listed in my answer and it didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Done.

It was only because I haven't been using **sa** as a login. Only I changed my database to **sa** and used that in the connection string. It worked.

Discussion:

Question

it could be from the dbo being mapped to a Windows account that sometimes is invalid. 'dbo' really is the user that created the database. This problem happen for instance if I create the sample on the SQL instance on my laptop at work, then I go home and continue from home. At home I don't have access to the domain ActiveDirectory and the samples sudenly stop working because 'dbo' is realy my Windows account and is no longer available. Messages (like notifications) sent by 'dbo' sit in sys.transmissions_queue with a status complaining 'Could not retrieve info about user '...' from the domain controller'. Running EXECUTE AS USER='dbo' in the database also shows the same error happening. The fix in this case is to change 'dbo' to a login that is valid, e.g.  by running ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::[dbname] TO [sa];

Answer (score -2):

```
  using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);

            string commandText = "select ID, status from dbo.VendorSetup";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn);

            SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(cmd);

            dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dbChangeNotification);

            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var employee = new VendorSetup
                {
                    ID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"]),
                    status = reader["status"].ToString(),
                    //Age = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Age"])
                };

                employees.Add(employee);
            }
        }

        return employees;
    }

    private void dbChangeNotification(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        _hubcontext.Clients.All.SendAsync("displayNotification");
    }
```

Comment: Your answer does not add anything useful to the other answers and comments. And simply dumping a bunch of code does not help understand where the problem was either...